# Assigning Vector Values

Tags: c++, vector, assign

I'm working on a simple dice game project which requires me to instantiate several copies of a custom class.

```
vector <Player> playerList;

playerList.resize(totalNumPlayers); //totalNum is grabbed from cin

for (int x = 0; x < totalNumPlayers; x++) 
{
    playerList.at(x).setname("Player" + to_string(x + 1));
    //playerList[x] = p;
    playerList.at(x).printName();
    cout << playerList[0].returnName() << " " << playerList[1].returnName() << " " << playerList[2].returnName() << endl;
}
```

Player Class:

```
//Declarations
string playerName;
int playerChips;

Player::Player()
{
    //Default constructor for when player is created
    playerChips = 3;
    playerName = "DEFAULT_PLAYER_NAME";
}

void Player::setname(string var)
{
    playerName = var;
}

string Player::returnName()
{
    return(playerName);
}

void Player::printName()
{
    cout << playerName << endl;
}

void Player::addChips(int x)
{
    playerChips += x;
}

void Player::removeChips(int x)
{
    playerChips -= x;
}

int Player::returnChips()
{
    return(playerChips);
}
```

I've noticed that on every iteration during the original forloop, the playerList[x] value is always the same. For instance, if totalNumPlayers = 3, playerList[0], playerList[1], and playerList[2] are all effected by the setName line. Therefore, when I use cout for PL 1,2, and 3, it always prints

Player1, Player1, Player1
then
Player2, Player2, Player2
ect.

Why are the references to each index not unique to their own object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. You have defined `string playerName;` in the global namespace (you have not given the complete structure of your source file) and therefore, whenever you invoke `Player::setname`, you modify this global variable and as a result, when you invoke `Player::printName()` in your for loop, you just read this variable that is shared among all instances of `Player`. To fix this, move this variable into the `Player` class:

```
class Player
{
private: 
    string playerName;
public:
    Player();
    void setname(string var);
    string returnName();
    string Player::returnName();
    void printName();
    void addChips(int x);
    void printName();
    // and the rest of your declarations
};
```